# I can't update my string value with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

Its like the simplest of cases you can think of,

I have a select which updates a string according to the value which is supposed to update a property of the select itself (its background color)

I am using React hooks and Styled Components to achieve this.

I have Redux to be able to bind it an immutable array of colors in the future.

The question is simple, why can't I update the state? I have tried to print it and it is always an empty string.

Here is my styles file

```
let currentColor = '';

const SelectColor = styled.div`
  select{
    background-color: ${currentColor || 'black'};
  }
  .label{
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
`;
```

This is the component that isn't updating the selectValue for reasons I cannot grasp(I have attempted to console log it and it returns always empty string).
I have checked the documentation a couple times and it seems like its meant to be updated this way so I am clueless...

```
const SelectComponent = ({
  disabled,
  colorList,
  label,
  onSelect,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setSelectValue(e.target.value);
      console.log(selectValue);
    },colorList
  );

  return (
    <SelectColor>
      <span className='label'>{label}</span>
      <select onChange={e=>handleChange(e)}>
        {
          colorList.map(color =>
          <option key={color} value={color}>{color}</option>)
        };
      </select>
    </SelectColor>
  );
};

SelectComponent.propTypes = {
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  hourValue: PropTypes.number,
  projectName: PropTypes.string,
};


export default SelectComponent;
```

Comment: Your using a memoized callback, so unless `colorList` changes `e.target.value` is never going to change.

Comment: you should probably change the dependency array of `useCallback` from `colorList` to `[colorList]`. This causes changes to the variable to trigger the update and not changes to the items inside colorList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some fixes, check the comments in the code:

```
// SelectComponent
const SelectComponent = ({
  disabled,
  colorList,
  label,
  onSelect,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState('');

  // Make this a function, not an arrow function. 
  // It's unnecessary in this case due to not needing a binding
  function handleChange(e) {
    setSelectValue(e.target.value);
  }

  // send currentColor as a prop to your styled component and remove 
  // the arrow onChange, not needed.
  return (
    <SelectColor currentColor={selectValue}>
      <span className='label'>{label}</span>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {
          colorList.map(color =>
          <option key={color} value={color}>{color}</option>)
        };
      </select>
    </SelectColor>
  );
};

SelectComponent.propTypes = {
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  hourValue: PropTypes.number,
  projectName: PropTypes.string,
};


export default SelectComponent;
```

```
// Your styled components receives now a prop with the name currentColor.
// Use it inside the interpolation string ${} and set the value
const SelectColor = styled.div`
  select{
    background-color: ${(props) => props.currentColor || 'black'};
  }
  .label{
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
`;
```

Hope this helps! Ask whatever you feel necessary, I'll help if I'm available!

Answer (score 1):

Your handlechange function is a bit strange to me as the function itself does not take in a variable. try writing it like this

```
 const handlestring = (e) => {
   setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
}
```